# Bootstrap overriding aspnetDisabled class

Tags: html, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to style an ASP.net web forms project and I have a data paging repeater consisting of asp-net `LinkButton`s.

The buttons all work fine, but Bootstrap is overriding the `aspnetDisabled` class and making disabled links look like they're enabled.

I have tried overriding the `a` styling in a `paginator` css class I have created, but have no joy.

---

This is how the paginator should look:

[image: This is how it should look]

---

And this is how it looks with boostrap.css included:

[image: Bootstrap breaks paginator]

---

This is the debug output from chrome:

[image: Chrome debug]

---

How can I override the offending bootstrap styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the `bootstrap pagination disabled` class in the `aspNetDisabled` class :

```
.aspNetDisabled{
  color: #777777;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

**Doc** : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/pagination.less on line 62